# What's the song when young Kureo Mado is facing the one-eyed owl on episode 2 of Root A?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

There's a song in *Tokyo Ghoul: Root A* in the second episode where young Kureo Mado is facing the one-eyed owl, and then Arima steps up to fight.

What is the song that plays?

Comment: Would you like to add a timestamp and episode number to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a bit of time to track it down, but managed to find it.
The song is called **FUKUROU** off the Tokyo Ghoul Root A soundtrack.

You can listen to it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmIa4ScvqZo)